# Response Xpath extraction Error for some Cases

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm Writing a **scraper** using *Scrappy* to Extract Data from an E-Commerce Site. Its a Recursive **scraper** which visists and parses pages,the code is as follows:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from kohls_scraper.items import KohlsItem

class kohlsspider(CrawlSpider):
    name="Kohls"
    allowed_domains=["www.kohls.com"]

    start_urls=\
    [
        "http://www.kohls.com/catalog/womens-active-clothing.jsp?CN=4294720878+4294737782+4294719810&cc=womens-LN3.7-S-workout",
    ]

    rules=(
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/product/prd.*')),follow=True,callback='parse_stuff')
        )

    def parse_stuff(self,response):
        sel=Selector(response=response)
        data=KohlsItem()
        data['prod_name']=sel.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
        data['prod_name']=data['prod_name'][0].encode('utf-8','ignore')

        data['colors']=sel.xpath('//div[@class="pdp-product-swatch"]/a/@title').extract()

        data['price']=sel.xpath('//*[@id="pdp-Pricing"]/div[2]/div[2]/text()').extract()        
        print('\n\n\n\nProduct Colors :',data['colors'],'\n\n\n\n')
        #data['price']=data['price'][0].encode('utf-8')
        #data['sizes']=
        #print('\n\n\n\nProduct Name :',data['prod_name'],'\n\n\n\n')
        return data
```

Now the problems is that from the Response Pages, **Products_Name** is extracted perfectly ok, but extracting **Colors** and **prices** is not working. Those are showing as *None* elements. I've checked the **Xpath** and it looks ok. The Output is as follows :

```
Product Colors : [] 

2016-10-14 17:06:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.kohls.com/product/prd-2445710/womens-columbia-three-lakes-fleece-jacket.jsp?bvrrp=9025%2Freviews%2Fproduct%2F3%2F2445710.htm>
{'colors': [], 'prod_name': b"Women's Columbia Three Lakes Fleece Jacket "}
NAA


Product Colors : [] 

2016-10-14 17:06:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.kohls.com/product/prd-2526246/womens-tek-gear-cowlneck-tunic-dress.jsp?bvrrp=9025%2Freviews%2Fproduct%2F4%2F2526246.htm>
{'colors': [], 'prod_name': b"Women's Tek Gear\xc2\xae Cowlneck Tunic Dress"}
NAA

Product Colors : []
```

I can't seem to figure out why is the other two items not being extracted through Xpath while Product_name is extracted perfectely ok. Can somebody **Help**? A little Help would be apprecieated...

Comment: Open the site with a web browser and *deactivated Javascript*. Then you will see the page as Scrapy is getting it. That should get you going.

Comment: @Markus Thanks for the Advice..... That Helped Upto Some extent